# d3.js: How to add value below the label in donut chart

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

I am new to d3.js and what I have achieved till now is, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/ypdw96v9/) using tutorials and videos.

Now I am trying to add the `dataset.value` below the label text as shown in the figure. [image]

```
var dataset = [{
  label: 'On trip',
  value: 35
}, {
  label: 'parked',
  value: 65 
}];
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your append text code with following code.

```
text.enter()
 .append("text")
 .attr("dy", ".35em")
 .append('svg:tspan')
 .attr('x', 0)
 .attr('dy', 0)
 .text(function(d) { return d.data.label; })
 .append('svg:tspan')
 .attr('x', 0)
 .attr('dy', 20)
 .text(function(d) { return d.data.value; });
```

Append two `tspan` to your `text` element

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypdw96v9/8/) here

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this:

```
    var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(data), key);
  //make a group  
    var textg = text.enter().append("g");
  //to the group append text for label
    textg
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.label;
        });
  //to the group append text for value  
    textg.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "1.95em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.value; });
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0k3qrs2c/)

Comment: Both of you gave the correct answers, it's a shame I have only one right answer to give.

Comment: np the one you selected is definitely a better answer :)