# How to break text in d3.js which is called from data

Tags: d3.js

I want to pull up the firstname & lastname from json database & it should be shown in two lines.....

What needs to be changed in the below code ?

`.text(function(d) { return d.firstname +"<br/>"+ d.lastname;});`

Comment: Use tspan within text see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791143/how-to-dynamically-display-a-multiline-text-in-d3-js

Comment: You would have to use foreign object and tspan as Cyril has said or split it into multiple text elements so one for first name and one for last and position accordingly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868310/d3-js-how-to-add-value-below-the-label-in-donut-chart/35869583#35869583 this will also help add tspan with x and dy

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot directly add an html element directly.

You can use foreignObject.

```
svg.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", "50px")
  .attr("height", "50px")
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .html(function(d) { 
    return (d.firstname + " <br>  "  + "     " + d.lastname);
  });
```